# how to make a recursive function asyncronous with limited concurrency using PLimit in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Basically what im trying to do is a recursive http request that will run in a limited parallel requests for faster execution and get a result using await.

```js
async function sitetree(subsiteurl, subsitetitle) {

    var url = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com" + subsiteurl + "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title"

    logtext(subsiteurl + "\n", sitetree_file)
    sitecount++
    stats()

    ajax(url, global_headers, "verbose").then(function (subsites) {
        requestcount++
        stats()


        subsites.d.results.forEach(function (data) {

            sitetree(data.ServerRelativeUrl, data.Title);

        });

    }).catch(function (error) {

        console.log(error)

    })

}
```

Comment: And what have you tried yourself to handle this parallelism?  Where did it fail?  If you haven't yet tried yourself, where have you looked for information?  What wasn't clear?

Comment: i want to use the library P-LIMIT but in the case above is recursive and i couldnt:     arr_limit.push(
        plimit(function () {
            return get_sites(url, list_data)
        })
    )